# Escaping single quotes **with** an alias

Tags: bash, sed, alias

I am aware that there are many questions asked in the past about escaping single quotes, but none of them addresses this challenge, i.e how to do it **with an alias**.

I have already successfully defined many aliases to replace sed/awk/grep/perl commands which use regex in the last release of bash (4.4.0(1)).

For instance, the following **alias can escape double quotes** in any string:

```
alias esc_double_quotes=$'sed \'s|"|\\\\"|g\''
string="JC's alias to escape \"double quotes\""
echo "$string" | esc_double_quotes
JC's alias to escape \"double quotes\"
```

However, when it comes to **escaping single quotes with an alias, it seems that the mission is impossible**.

I have already tried **5 different methods** which all fail for different reasons:

```
# 1) My first technique
alias esc_single_quotes=$'sed \"s|'|\\\\'|g\"'
# 2) My second technique
alias esc_single_quotes="sed 's|'\''|\\\'\''|g'"
# 3) My third technique
alias esc_single_quotes="sed \"s|'|\\\\'|g\""
# 4) Technique inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings?answertab=active#tab-top
alias esc_single_quotes='sed '"'"'s|'|\\\\'|g'"'"
# 5) Technique inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1315213/revisions
alias esc_single_quotes='sed '\''s|'|\\\\'|g'\'''
```

Would anyone live up to this impossible challenge & prove me wrong?

Comment: Why don't you turn it into a shell function instead?

Comment: Escape single quotes for what purpose?

Comment: The answers to the other question show how to do it and the fact that you're using an alias is _irrelevant_, the same quoting rules apply (see _enzotib_'s answer which is very similar to _Vouze_'s one here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can escape everything at once with

```
printf "%q\n" "$string"
```

But here is your answer :

```
alias esc_single_quotes="sed \"s/'/\\\\\\\\'/g\""
echo  "$string" | esc_single_quotes 
JC\'s alias to escape "double quotes"
```

or :

```
alias esc_single_quotes='sed "s/'\''/\\\\'\''/g"'
echo  "$string" | esc_single_quotes 
JC\'s alias to escape "double quotes"
```

Comment: Bravo and thanks :-) I won't ask why so many backslashes are needed though. However, the first part of your answer does not answer the question because it escapes also spaces and double quotes.

Comment: You need so many backslashes, because the string will be interpreted twice by the shell and once by sed. So you need 2x2x2=8 backslashes in order to have one at the end. Type "alias" alone to see the first level of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

To help our eyes, let's simplified it:

```
$ alias esc_single_quotes='sed "s|\x27|\x5c\x5c\x27|g"'

$ echo "this is 'something'"
this is 'something'

$ echo "this is 'something'" |esc_single_quotes
this is \'something\'
```

Comment: @jean This solution is nog working? I am just using single quotes and backslash hex numbrs...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function esc_double_quotes() {
    echo $* | sed 's|"|\\\\"|g'
}
```

Comment: @don_crissti, Don't leave me in suspense here, what did I miss?  I tried to show the right way to define the alias that he needed.

Comment: @don_crissti, Oh I got that part, but from the [help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) - Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a *viable* alternative. - So I thought it was viable.

Comment: The question talks about how to escape SINLGE quotes, no?